# What application layer protocol does Google Goggles and Layar use?

Tags: sockets, video, streaming, layar, google-goggles

These applications stream video from client app to their own server. I am interested in knowing what type of  protocol they use? I am planning on building a similar application but I dont know how to go about the video streaming. Once I get the stream to my server I will use OpenCV to do some processing and return the result to the client.

Comment: do they? I can't believe they stream video from client devices to a server.

Comment: @SatelliteSD What else would you call it? Nevertheless I need a technique to send video from client to a remote server. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to send only a minimum of data and do the processing as much as possible on the client. Since sending the whole video stream is a huge waste of traffic (and can not be done in realtime I think)

I would use a TCP connection to send an intermediate result to the server, that the server can process further. The desing of that communication depends on what you are sending and what you want to do with it.

You can wrap it in xml for instance, or serialize an object and so on.